# Use custom charset in Jackson CsvMapper

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

Is it possible to use custom encoding with the Jackson CsvMapper? I need the CSV to be encoded with Windows-1252, not the default UTF-8.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
class CSVService(private val mapper: CsvMapper) {
   
  fun <T : CsvResponse> writeAsCSV(result: List<T>, resultClass: KClass<T>, separatorChar: Char = ',', encoding: Charset = Charsets.WINDOWS_1252): String {
    mapper.schemaFor(resultClass.java).withHeader().withColumnSeparator(separatorChar)
    return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(result).toString(encoding) // does not work. 
  }

}
```

It seems like the object mapper `writeValueAsBytes` method has UTF-8 hard-coded.
Can someone show with an example of how to configure the objectmapper to use a different encoding?

Thanks in advance.
Any help is appreciated.

---

Using `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.11.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson Javadoc specifies that method writeValueAsBytes encoding is forced to UTF-8.

To customize charset, you'll have to create an in-memory writer as intermediate output.

Example:

```
val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
OutputStreamWriter(buffer, encoding).use {
    mapper.writeValue(it, result) 
}
val bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
```

**EDIT**:

On second look, I see you try to read back byte array to string. That operation will break any effort to customize encoding. Java internal system use UTF-16 encoding for text representation, and the encoding provided as `toString(encoding)` input serves to decode bytes from the originating charset (in your case windows by default).

It won't serve for further  writing, because it's the writer that is responsible for the encoding, not the content. So, once you've written your byte array, either you return it as is, or you'll have to customize encoding later on the final encoder.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer. The fedback was very valuable. I solved it by *not* converting it in the mapper and let Spring handle the encoding.